# Spark Streaming NoClassDefFoundError error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, lambda-architecture

I am trying to create Spark Kafka Cassandra Integration. Now I am able to connect to cassandra but when I m trying to create SparkStreamingContext object using

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(60))
```

I am able to import and write the above code. But when I m trying build and run the code, I m facing below error:

```
org/apache/spark/SparkConf
at KafkaSparkCassandra$.main(KafkaSparkCassandra.scala:38)
at KafkaSparkCassandra.main(KafkaSparkCassandra.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at       sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at        sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.SparkConf
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 7 more
```

now I am not able to understand why I m unable to create SparkStreaming Object at runtime.

Please Help. As I m new using the whole scala and lambda Architecture stack.

below is the configuration inside build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies ++=Seq(
  "org.apache.spark"    %     "spark-core_2.10"                 %   "1.4.1",
  "com.datastax.spark"  %     "spark-cassandra-connector_2.10"  %   "1.4.0",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % "1.4.1",
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.12")

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.6.0" % "provided"


libraryDependencies += ("org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka" % "1.6.0").exclude("org.spark-project.spark", "unused")


/*
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka" % "1.6.0"  % "provided"
*/


javaOptions ++= Seq("-Xmx5G", "-XX:MaxPermSize=5G", "-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled"
```

below are the logs. Now M unable to print word count and also to store the same into cassandra db.

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.datastax.driver.core.SystemProperties).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/11/15 18:54:52 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.6.0
16/11/15 18:54:52 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/11/15 18:54:52 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: romit.srivastava
16/11/15 18:54:52 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: romit.srivastava
16/11/15 18:54:52 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(romit.srivastava); users with modify permissions: Set(romit.srivastava)
16/11/15 18:54:53 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 53789.
16/11/15 18:54:53 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
16/11/15 18:54:53 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
16/11/15 18:54:53 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriverActorSystem@192.168.56.1:53802]
16/11/15 18:54:53 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriverActorSystem' on port 53802.
16/11/15 18:54:54 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
16/11/15 18:54:54 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
16/11/15 18:54:54 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at C:\Users\romit.srivastava\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr-c60aeba8-a317-4066-99ce-71ec3595bdf3
16/11/15 18:54:54 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 2.4 GB
16/11/15 18:54:54 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
16/11/15 18:54:54 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
16/11/15 18:54:54 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4041. Attempting port 4042.
16/11/15 18:54:54 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4042. Attempting port 4043.
16/11/15 18:54:54 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4043. Attempting port 4044.
16/11/15 18:54:54 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4044. Attempting port 4045.
16/11/15 18:54:54 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4045.
16/11/15 18:54:54 INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://192.168.56.1:4045
16/11/15 18:54:54 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
16/11/15 18:54:54 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 53814.
16/11/15 18:54:54 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 53814
16/11/15 18:54:54 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
16/11/15 18:54:54 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager localhost:53814 with 2.4 GB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, localhost, 53814)
16/11/15 18:54:54 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
16/11/15 18:54:55 INFO VerifiableProperties: Verifying properties
16/11/15 18:54:55 INFO VerifiableProperties: Property group.id is overridden to 
16/11/15 18:54:55 INFO VerifiableProperties: Property zookeeper.connect is overridden to 
16/11/15 18:54:58 INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /136.243.174.23:9042 added
16/11/15 18:54:58 INFO CassandraConnector: Connected to Cassandra cluster: Test Cluster
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO ForEachDStream: metadataCleanupDelay = -1
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO MappedDStream: metadataCleanupDelay = -1
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO ShuffledDStream: metadataCleanupDelay = -1
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO MappedDStream: metadataCleanupDelay = -1
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO FilteredDStream: metadataCleanupDelay = -1
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO FlatMappedDStream: metadataCleanupDelay = -1
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO MappedDStream: metadataCleanupDelay = -1
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO DirectKafkaInputDStream: metadataCleanupDelay = -1
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO DirectKafkaInputDStream: Slide time = 60000 ms
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO DirectKafkaInputDStream: Storage level = StorageLevel(false, false, false, false, 1)
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO DirectKafkaInputDStream: Checkpoint interval = null
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO DirectKafkaInputDStream: Remember duration = 60000 ms
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO DirectKafkaInputDStream: Initialized and validated org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.DirectKafkaInputDStream@2d1a0e90
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO MappedDStream: Slide time = 60000 ms
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO MappedDStream: Storage level = StorageLevel(false, false, false, false, 1)
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO MappedDStream: Checkpoint interval = null
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO MappedDStream: Remember duration = 60000 ms
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO MappedDStream: Initialized and validated org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.MappedDStream@678a042d
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO FlatMappedDStream: Slide time = 60000 ms
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO FlatMappedDStream: Storage level = StorageLevel(false, false, false, false, 1)
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO FlatMappedDStream: Checkpoint interval = null
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO FlatMappedDStream: Remember duration = 60000 ms
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO FlatMappedDStream: Initialized and validated org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.FlatMappedDStream@7d8e7cf5
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO FilteredDStream: Slide time = 60000 ms
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO FilteredDStream: Storage level = StorageLevel(false, false, false, false, 1)
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO FilteredDStream: Checkpoint interval = null
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO FilteredDStream: Remember duration = 60000 ms
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO FilteredDStream: Initialized and validated org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.FilteredDStream@183e79df
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO MappedDStream: Slide time = 60000 ms
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO MappedDStream: Storage level = StorageLevel(false, false, false, false, 1)
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO MappedDStream: Checkpoint interval = null
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO MappedDStream: Remember duration = 60000 ms
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO MappedDStream: Initialized and validated org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.MappedDStream@652d8ac6
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO ShuffledDStream: Slide time = 60000 ms
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO ShuffledDStream: Storage level = StorageLevel(false, false, false, false, 1)
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO ShuffledDStream: Checkpoint interval = null
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO ShuffledDStream: Remember duration = 60000 ms
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO ShuffledDStream: Initialized and validated org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ShuffledDStream@52b15122
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO MappedDStream: Slide time = 60000 ms
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO MappedDStream: Storage level = StorageLevel(false, false, false, false, 1)
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO MappedDStream: Checkpoint interval = null
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO MappedDStream: Remember duration = 60000 ms
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO MappedDStream: Initialized and validated org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.MappedDStream@5c56f655
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO ForEachDStream: Slide time = 60000 ms
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO ForEachDStream: Storage level = StorageLevel(false, false, false, false, 1)
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO ForEachDStream: Checkpoint interval = null
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO ForEachDStream: Remember duration = 60000 ms
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO ForEachDStream: Initialized and validated org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream@37cd8c81
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO ForEachDStream: metadataCleanupDelay = -1
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO MappedDStream: metadataCleanupDelay = -1
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO ShuffledDStream: metadataCleanupDelay = -1
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO MappedDStream: metadataCleanupDelay = -1
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO FilteredDStream: metadataCleanupDelay = -1
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO FlatMappedDStream: metadataCleanupDelay = -1
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO MappedDStream: metadataCleanupDelay = -1
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO DirectKafkaInputDStream: metadataCleanupDelay = -1
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO DirectKafkaInputDStream: Slide time = 60000 ms
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO DirectKafkaInputDStream: Storage level = StorageLevel(false, false, false, false, 1)
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO DirectKafkaInputDStream: Checkpoint interval = null
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO DirectKafkaInputDStream: Remember duration = 60000 ms
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO DirectKafkaInputDStream: Initialized and validated org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.DirectKafkaInputDStream@2d1a0e90
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO MappedDStream: Slide time = 60000 ms
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO MappedDStream: Storage level = StorageLevel(false, false, false, false, 1)
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO MappedDStream: Checkpoint interval = null
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO MappedDStream: Remember duration = 60000 ms
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO MappedDStream: Initialized and validated org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.MappedDStream@678a042d
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO FlatMappedDStream: Slide time = 60000 ms
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO FlatMappedDStream: Storage level = StorageLevel(false, false, false, false, 1)
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO FlatMappedDStream: Checkpoint interval = null
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO FlatMappedDStream: Remember duration = 60000 ms
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO FlatMappedDStream: Initialized and validated org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.FlatMappedDStream@7d8e7cf5
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO FilteredDStream: Slide time = 60000 ms
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO FilteredDStream: Storage level = StorageLevel(false, false, false, false, 1)
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO FilteredDStream: Checkpoint interval = null
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO FilteredDStream: Remember duration = 60000 ms
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO FilteredDStream: Initialized and validated org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.FilteredDStream@183e79df
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO MappedDStream: Slide time = 60000 ms
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO MappedDStream: Storage level = StorageLevel(false, false, false, false, 1)
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO MappedDStream: Checkpoint interval = null
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO MappedDStream: Remember duration = 60000 ms
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO MappedDStream: Initialized and validated org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.MappedDStream@652d8ac6
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO ShuffledDStream: Slide time = 60000 ms
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO ShuffledDStream: Storage level = StorageLevel(false, false, false, false, 1)
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO ShuffledDStream: Checkpoint interval = null
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO ShuffledDStream: Remember duration = 60000 ms
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO ShuffledDStream: Initialized and validated org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ShuffledDStream@52b15122
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO MappedDStream: Slide time = 60000 ms
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO MappedDStream: Storage level = StorageLevel(false, false, false, false, 1)
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO MappedDStream: Checkpoint interval = null
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO MappedDStream: Remember duration = 60000 ms
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO MappedDStream: Initialized and validated org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.MappedDStream@5c56f655
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO ForEachDStream: Slide time = 60000 ms
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO ForEachDStream: Storage level = StorageLevel(false, false, false, false, 1)
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO ForEachDStream: Checkpoint interval = null
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO ForEachDStream: Remember duration = 60000 ms
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO ForEachDStream: Initialized and validated org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream@3e3f4b04
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO RecurringTimer: Started timer for JobGenerator at time 1479216360000
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO JobGenerator: Started JobGenerator at 1479216360000 ms
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO JobScheduler: Started JobScheduler
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO StreamingContext: StreamingContext started
16/11/15 18:55:00 INFO CassandraConnector: Disconnected from Cassandra cluster: Test Cluster
16/11/15 18:55:30 INFO JobGenerator: Stopping JobGenerator immediately
16/11/15 18:55:30 INFO RecurringTimer: Stopped timer for JobGenerator after time -1
16/11/15 18:55:30 INFO JobGenerator: Stopped JobGenerator
16/11/15 18:55:30 INFO JobScheduler: Stopped JobScheduler
16/11/15 18:55:30 INFO StreamingContext: StreamingContext stopped successfully
16/11/15 18:55:30 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://192.168.56.1:4045
16/11/15 18:55:30 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
16/11/15 18:55:30 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
16/11/15 18:55:30 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
16/11/15 18:55:30 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
16/11/15 18:55:30 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
16/11/15 18:55:30 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
16/11/15 18:55:30 WARN StreamingContext: StreamingContext has already been stopped
16/11/15 18:55:30 INFO SparkContext: SparkContext already stopped.
16/11/15 18:55:30 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Shutting down remote daemon.
16/11/15 18:55:30 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
16/11/15 18:55:30 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remoting shut down.
```

Comment: Provide some more code ! If you can provide a gist that would be great !

Comment: please provide pom or sbt file? What is scope for spark libs ?

Comment: Are you adding the --jars and the jar of KafkaSparkCassandra?

Comment: @FaigB  i have added build.sbt file.

Comment: @ShivanshSrivastava i have shared build.sbt file.

Comment: Why are you make streaming inside the provided scope . Remove it and then try to re run

Comment: @ShivanshSrivastava , if m removing that then I m unable to import SparkStreamingContext, means compilation error.

Comment: @HromitProdigy: Just remove the provided  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.6.0" like this !

Comment: @ShivanshSrivastava, finally m able to run through , m able to run kafka , create topic connect to cassandra , but but  but m not able to do word count print and also to save it into cassandra. I m attaching logs can you please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was primarily due to different versions of spark modules. By fixing the version I was able to run the code.

Further I was able to do word count and save it to cassandra.